# EXCEL: VLookupwith dummy variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, indicator

I have data that has dates, returns, and two columns of dummy variables. I would like to know how to use a formula to only show data when the dummy variable indicates a hit.
My data looks like this:

```
    date      Return    A   B
    1/1/2014    0.18    0   0
    1/2/2014    0.97    0   1
    1/3/2014    0.73    0   0
    1/4/2014    0.85    1   0
    1/5/2014    0.19    1   0
    1/6/2014    0.80    0   0
    1/7/2014    0.50    0   0
    1/8/2014    0.27    0   0
    1/9/2014    0.94    0   0
    1/10/2014   0.40    0   0
    1/11/2014   0.56    0   0
    1/12/2014   0.40    1   0
    1/13/2014   0.40    1   0
    1/14/2014   0.43    1   1
    1/15/2014   0.44    0   1
    1/16/2014   0.90    0   0
    1/17/2014   0.35    0   0
```

And I would like it to output two tables:

```
    DUMMY A TABLE           
    date    Return  A   B
    1/4/2014    0.85    1   0
    1/5/2014    0.19    1   0
    1/12/2014   0.40    1   0
    1/13/2014   0.40    1   0
    1/14/2014   0.43    1   1
```

and

```
    DUMMY B TABLE           
    date    Return  A   B
    1/2/2014    0.97    0   1
    1/14/2014   0.43    1   1
    1/15/2014   0.44    0   1
```

I have figured how to do it using sort copy / paste, but I would like a formula to make it a more efficient template

Comment: Unfortunately, no as it is not scaleable. In the workbooks I am working with, I have 6-9 dummy variables that I have to run fairly often with different data. I am currently copy/pasting, but if I could code it, I could save a ton of time.

Comment: Each time I run the report, the number of indicators in each columns change. Would a macro be able to only pull the ones that are equal to 1 when that number of indicators changes each time?

Comment: Have you tried pivot tables?

Comment: What do you mean? Pivot it 90 degrees?

Comment: I'll take that as a no :)  There is an excel function called pivot tables (use Excel help to learn how to use).  It allows you to create filterable tables over other tables (and accumulate data, but this is not one of your needs).  I'll add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 pivot tables in a table layout.

Set Date and Return as "Row Labels", and Report Filter on A (on one resultant pivot) and B (on the other pivot).  You don't need any "Values"

This should result in (for Table A) - (note I used random returns):
[image]

The mechanics of creating and formatting one differs slightly in different versions, but you just select your data table and Insert->Pivot Table.